# how to find the average for a array and to store multiple values in a array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, dictionary, key-value-store

How to store multiple results for my program in an array?
For each person in my array I need to store 3 results, but everytime I do this I get an error when the program is run.

I can't find the average score for each person in the 3 arrays when the program is run.

I'M NEW TO PYTHON.

```
import operator 
print("if form1 enter x, if form2 enter y,if form 3 enter z")
print("to view all results enter allscore")
x={"guv":1,"jane":4,"adam":5,"luiz":8,"elizabeth":9,"paul":10,"guv":3}

sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True) #sorts x from high to low

sorted(x.items()) #sorts x alphabetically

y={"adrian":0,"anna":9,"david":7,"matt":10,"micheal":5}

sorted(y.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

sorted(y.items())

z={"gus":6,"mohammed":6,"winston":9,"barry":9,"ping":3}

sorted(z.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

sorted(z.items()) # 

allscore={} 

allscore.update(x) # to get data from array x
allscore.update(y) # to get data from array y
allscore.update(z) # to get data from array z
#stores all data in this array
```

Comment: Why are you sorting a list of keys? That won't affect the dictionary.

Comment: You are also confusing `sorted` with `sort`.

Comment: Its the criteria that i need to match as i need to sort from high to low and by alphabetical order which i have achieved now i need to get the average score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store multiple values for each user, you can use [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

```
scores = {
    "guv": (1, 2, 3),
    "jane": (4, 5, 6),
    "luiz": (7, 8, 9),
}
```

You can then get the average for all users with the following loop:

```
for name in scores:
    average = sum(scores[name]) / len(scores[name])
    print("Average for " + name + ": " + str(average))
```

If you want to be able to add scores, use [lists](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead.

For printing the scores in alphabetical order:

```
for name in sorted(scores):
    print("Scores for " + name + ": " + str(scores[name]))
```

For printing the scores from highest average to lowest average:

```
averages = {
    name: sum(scores[name]) / len(scores[name])
    for name in scores.keys()
}
for name in sorted(averages, key=averages.get, reverse=True):
    print("Average score for " + name + ": " + str(averages[name]))
```